# How to run Go program after making a CPU limit in a docker container?

Tags: docker, go, networking

I have created a docker container for my Go program and I am able to run that code within that container successfully. I have created a docker network to run that code. I have used the following command:

```
docker run --network network_name -it go_program Github_repo -l 10000 -secio
```

Now to test my program I am trying to provide a maximum fixed cpu resource(40%) to the container. I have used the following command to do that:

```
sudo docker run -it --cpus=".4" ubuntu
```

But after that when I try to run my program it always says it doesn't recognize the command:

```
shihab@shihab-VirtualBox:~$ sudo docker run -it --cpus=".4" ubuntu
root@67637cc7edd1:/# sudo docker run --network network_name -it go_program Github_repo -l 10000 -secio
bash: sudo: command not found
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , becuase when you run `sudo docker run -it --cpus=".4" ubuntu`
you go into the container , and then you run the second command inside the container which is not working

Instead you need to just run one command , all in one:

```
sudo docker run --network network_name --cpus=".4" -it go_program Github_repo -l 10000 -secio
```

here I assume that go_program is the docker image containing your go program

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps.